# Is there a difference between defining a destructor and not?

Tags: c#

Is there a difference in the garbage collection if I define the `~Example` part or not?

```
class Example
{
    public void Display()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("hi");
    }

    ~Example()//**does giving this part or not has any effects in garbage collection**
    {
    }
}
```

and

```
class Example
{
    public void Display()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you calling the destructor? all I can see is you defining one

Comment: @UnholySheep, calling a destructor? You never call a destructor directly, it's automatic.

Comment: @walther: But OP wants to know the difference in calling it or not, then he should define where it is called, or not.

Comment: [Destructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx)

Comment: @PatrickHofman, OP doesn't understand a thing obviously, yet it's obvious from his example he asks something different than he actually means. See the body of the question, not only the title :)

Comment: @walther: If those two don't match, vote to close as unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# is a garbage collected language. This means that the .NET framework, in which code written in C# is executed, has a mechanism for the memory management. We don't have like in C++ to care about the destruction of the created objects, in order we don't have a high memory footprint or memory leaks. That's the job of Garbage Collector.

As it is stated more formally in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx)

> In general, C# does not require as much memory management as is needed
>   when you develop with a language that does not target a runtime with
>   garbage collection. This is because the .NET Framework garbage
>   collector implicitly manages the allocation and release of memory for
>   your objects. However, when your application encapsulates unmanaged
>   resources such as windows, files, and network connections, you should
>   use destructors to free those resources. When the object is eligible
>   for destruction, the garbage collector runs the Finalize method of the
>   object.

However the concept of destructors exist also in C# and as in other languages are used for the destruction of instances of classes. Furthermore a destructor **cannot** be called. It is invoked automatically.

For instance, if we declare the following class:

```
class Customer
{
    ~Customer()
    {
        // Here we place our clean up statements.
    }
}
```

The destructor will implicitly call the `Finalize` method on the base class of the object. As it is explained in the above link this code would be translated to the following one by the C# compiler:

```
protected override void Finalize()
{
    try
    {
        // Here goes our clean up statements.
    }
    finally
    {
        base.Finalize();
    }
}
```

> This means that the Finalize method is called *recursively* **for all**
>   **instances in the inheritance chain**, from the most-derived to the
>   least-derived.

In any case you should keep in mind the following:

> The programmer **has no control over when the destructor is called**
>   because this is determined by the garbage collector. The garbage
>   collector checks for objects that are no longer being used by the
>   application. If it considers an object eligible for destruction, it
>   calls the destructor (if any) and reclaims the memory used to store
>   the object. Destructors are also called when the program exits.

Answer (score 0):

If the destructor actually had some code in it that is executing, than yes, of course that would be a difference, however you can't guarantee the time when it would be called etc.
Also, you ask a question about asp.net, yet you post code from a console application?

Answer (score 0):

C# has built in mechanism for freeing up un used objects or invalid objects. It runs periodically and cleans up the memory.

There is no need to write any explicit code/functionality to implement this.

For more details refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)